# Generic type argument in java generics

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Is there a way that I can pass a generic type to a generic class like

```
interface Wrapper<T, R> {}

interface Result<T, Wrapper<T, R>> {
    R getResult();
}
```

Here `Result` takes `Wrapper` one of the type with type arguments `T and R`. `getResult` method in `Result` interface returns `R`.

What I did is below,

```
interface Result<T, W> {
    <K> K getResult();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this in java.

Comment: `Wrapper` in `interface Result<T, Wrapper<T, R>` is not using your existing `Wrapper<T, R>` interface. It's hiding it by declaring a new type parameter of the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a separate type argument for a `Result` interface. Something like this:

```java
interface Result<T, R, W extends Wrapper<T, R>> {
    R getResult();
}
```

Now you can use `W` inside the result to represent the `Wrapper` or `T` and `R` to represent wrapper components. It's possible though that `W` is completely unnecessary for you and having `T` and `R` is enough.